# This is a bit abstract, but can you get a div to start at one of the bottom corners?

Tags: javascript, css, html, positioning

Maybe there's an easy answer, but I don't know it.  I know you can float right, but is there anyway to position something at the bottom of a box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning. Absolute positions relative to its first positioned ancestor. If there is none it defaults to the document. So I gave it a parent with `relative`.

http://jsfiddle.net/DSpkv/

```css
#parent { position: relative }
#foo { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="foo"></div>
</div>
```